# Calling Select() on WPF text box doesn't do anything

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I'm using a WPF TextBox, and I'm calling the `Select()` method to make a selection. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work **unless** I select something manually first. Can someone suggest as to why it happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does your textbox have focus when you call the Select method?

The selection will not show unless it has focus, but the common way for the textbox to get focus is by clicking on it...which deselects the text. This behaviour could give the impression that it's not working.

Calling TextBox.Focus() after (or before) calling Select() should fix it.

Comment: Why aren't those things in the Select documentation? It would keep alot of frustrations from beginners like me.

Comment: Is there a way to select without being focused to implement 'Find' feature?