# TextBox (PasswordBox) SelectAll method doesn't work

Tags: wpf, textbox, selectall, passwordbox

I have some concept question here. I know how to select all text in `TextBox` or in `PasswordBox`. Via `GotKeyboardFocus` and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` events, you know. This works fine.

XAML:

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="PasswordOnPreviewMouseDown"
GotKeyboardFocus="SelectAllPassword"
```

CodeBehind

```
private void SelectAllPassword(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pb = (sender as PasswordBox);
    if (pb != null)
        pb.SelectAll();
}

private void PasswordOnPreviewMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var pb = (sender as PasswordBox);
    if (pb != null)
        if (!pb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            pb.Focus();
        }
}
```

But question is - why **this** doesn't work?

XAML:

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="PasswordOnPreviewMouseDown"
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void PasswordOnPreviewMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _txtPassword.SelectAll();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Where `_txtPassword` - `TextBox` or `PasswordBox` control. So why I'm enforsed to `Focus` text control?

Comment: Hmm, cause I tested these both approaches

Comment: I know you did, but my question was how did you test it and how did the second approach fail the test ?

Comment: What means "How did it fail"? O_o Make your test-project in VS and test it yourself. All required code for testing I placed here.

Comment: In other words : how do you check if the text has been selected or not ?

Comment: Visually. Text does't highlighted by blue color

Comment: Are you really sure it implies it's not selected ? It does not. Text is highlighted if it's selected AND focused. You can try playing with focus using the tab key and see it for yourself.

Comment: Got you. You are right. But what does mean `SelectAll()` then? it seems `SelectAll()` doesn't have any sense without control to be focused?

Comment: It means it selects all the text inside the TextBox, and it does only that. It makes sense, for example if you have been binding on the SelectedText property.

Comment: Thx. I think your frase `Text is highlighted if it's selected AND focused.`- is answer on my question. You can form it as answer and I will accept it

Comment: Did u try to remove `e.Handled=true;` line from the code which is not working and checked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Select() on WPF text box doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487141/calling-select-on-wpf-text-box-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the selection is working.

You may feel that the text is not selected because it's not visually highlighted, but that's because the `TextBox` is not focused.

Try giving focus to your `TextBox` with the `Tab` key, you'll see the whole text highlighted.